# how can i "unload" an image with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an img tag that uses the ng-src directive.  The ng-src directive is bound to a property called $scope.photoUrl.  Once i have set the value of $scope.photoUrl, the image will load.  However, after that, i want to be able to "unload" the image...  that is, i want to be able to set the src of the img tag to nothing so that the image is removed from the screen.  However, i cannot find a way to accomplish this.  I have tried this, but nothing happens:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.photoUrl = '';
});
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?  Do I have to set the $scope.photoUrl to a transparent .gif and what not?

Comment: Why not just remove the img node entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting src to nothing won't make the image disappear properly, I think this behaviour differs from browser to browser, but if an image is broken (eg. no src) you likely get a red x where the image should be. You should hide the image tag instead. You can use the `ng-show` attribute and test for the emptiness of `photoUrl`.

Comment: This will work, but i'm needing to keep the same space allocated to the image.  I guess i could just wrap the img tag in a div that has explicit width and height, or i could set the ng-src to a transparent gif...

Comment: no, just make it's `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`